# Make a custom SLF4J Logger

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I have an application that uses slf4j for logging. Now I want to add a functionality that whenever I log an error a specific url get called.
Currently I added a wrapper method in application level that sends the http request then calls the logger method. But this way I miss some of the outputs and some exceptions just get logged without having the corresponding request sent.
I am trying to make my custom logger class. My problem is which classes should I extend (or interface to implement).
I can't extend the `Logger` class because its constructor is not public. Implementing the `Logger` interface seems daunting because all the methods are abstract. The `NOPLogger` doesn't have these problems but its `info` (or `error`...) methods are final and cannot be extended and they do nothing, guess hence the name.
I have already implemented the `ILoggerFactory` interface to return an instance of my own Logger.

Comment: Maybe something like this is what you're looking for? http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers

Comment: @martijnp I forgot to explicitly mention the logger is logback. The link you provided though probably what I want but it is log4j.

Comment: You could probably misuse [filters](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/filter/Filter.html). Just let everything pass your filter and if it is an error, additionally send your HTTP request.

Comment: @doublep Your suggestion worked like a charm. I'd accept it as an answer, oops guilty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logger library is Logback, you could misuse [filters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) for this. Just let everything pass your filter and if it is an error, additionally send your HTTP request.

Comment: This may sound like a hack but when it works then it's the correct answer.